# Removing .aspx extension from sitecore in ExecuteRequest pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, sitecore, sitecore7

Currently I am trying to remove .aspx extensions from sitecore URL's. A blog suggests that changing the following would fix this issue:

```
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true"
```

The problem is that this does not work for all code in our websites as some custom controls force the usage of .aspx.

What I was thinking is that if I can get into the pipeline before a response is sent back to the user I could change the URL to one that is more SEO friendly (no .aspx), I am trying to do this using the following code

```
public class CustomExecuteRequest : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest
{
    protected override void PerformRedirect(string url)
    {
        base.PerformRedirect(url.Replace(".aspx" , ""));
    }

    public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        PerformRedirect(args.Url.FilePathWithQueryString.Replace(".aspx", ""));

        //args.Url.FilePathWithQueryString = args.Url.FilePathWithQueryString.Replace(".aspx", "");

        //base.Process(args);
    }
}
```

The code is being hit and this solution works, however it is performing a redirect which is really not what I want to do, I would rather just have a regular request with the URL cleaned up. The problem is that the args variable has a read-only field (commented out below) that is used to actually create the URL.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can change the URL here, or perhaps somewhere else in the pipeline?

Comment: Have you considering going on a different direction like implementing a custom link provider ? You can find this sitecore scrapbook article useful http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Friendlier%20marketing%20URLs%20for%20Sitecore%206.aspx

Comment: Apart from setting `addAspxExtension` to false, any further restrictions that you want to enforce seems like a good job for the IIS UrlRewrite module.

Comment: Could you please clarify why your custom controls force a .aspx extension?

Comment: You should be able to just `addAspxExtension=false` in the default LinkProvider. Make sure you use `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()` whenever you render a link and it will take your setting into account. As Mark says, please clarify.

Comment: @jammykam I believe that part of the problem is that in other sites (we run a multi-site environment) we are not using the correct sitecore methods to retrieve links. So turning the `addAspxExtension` to false will not resolve, and the work is too great to fix this.

Comment: @nsgocev I have already reviewed that link and tried that method, but if for example I enter manually the URL into a web browser, the .aspx extension remains

Comment: @MarkLowe It's not entirely clear to me as I am new to Sitecore, but I believe that in some sections of code we may not be using the LinkManager to get URL's

Comment: You're going to be fighting a losing battle trying to find hacks for this. As others have suggested, the correct way of fixing this is to change other code to use the `LinkManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing inside the HttpRequestPipeline is certainly NOT the correct way to change links. As with any web application, any links on the page are returned to the client as content of the HTTP request. Redirecting during the request will not change the rendered content.

The only way to do this is the hard way:

- Find all the places in your source generating the links containing .aspx. A search for *"aspx"* inside the solution might help
- Find all references to UrlOptions and to LinkManager and check if *AddAspxExtension=true* is set manually as urlOptions.

Something like this would always produce a .aspx ending for example:

```
var urlOptions = UrlOptions.DefaultOptions;
urlOptions.AddAspxExtension = true;

LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the hard way of changing all your links to use link manager or if you are strapped for time then suggest something maybe outside of sitecore and use IIS urlrewrite module.